# Small diameter multimedia cable?

Tags: electrical, network

I would like to install multimedia outlets (RJ45) in my house. The installation tubing is diam. 20mm (inside is 13.9mm). In the worse case, I have a diam. 6.5mm cable inside. So I would be able to add an additional 13.9 - 6.5 - 2.5 (mechanical play) = diam 5 mm multimedia cable.

As it would be quite a tough job, I am looking for a Cat 6a cable the smallest possible.

Where should I look for it?

Comment: Radio Shack or BBY.

Comment: I see that you are a "new contributor"...one of the basic expectations  here at SE is for you do to some reasonable amount of research on your own, not ask us to do your research for you. Do some searches, spend some time and I'm sure you'll answer your own question.   Also, "shopping" questions are off topic here....it's more of a "how do I do this?" site.

Comment: This is a how to do question. Perhaps I am asking the wrong question and I am looking for a magic flat cable or something else. Who knows?

Comment: You can get 3mm cable with 12 fibers in it, but then you need to change your media type.

Comment: Do you mean multimedia or ethernet?   Assuming ethernet.  Your options depend on how many rooms and where all the conduits start and end.  You could use fiber.  You could, to a point, daisy chain switches so you don't need multiple cables in one conduit. You could build just a wired backbone and use wifi.

Comment: If it has to be cat6 cable, then look for a cable "without spline" because they are a smaller diameter than cable with a bulky spline in the middle. Also, use plenty of wire lubricant "fish fluid" when feeding the fish and when pulling the cable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be hard knowing what to search for in the first place if you don’t know the domain and the terminology.  This sounds like in-wall, so you’d want to search for “riser” or “horizontal” solid conductor cable.  There’s not much more to do than search for options and check specs to see what is thin enough.

I’ve run across bulk stranded cable as small as 3.75mm diameter, and since you have conduit you can technically run whatever you want in it, but just be aware that most RJ45 wall jacks are intended for use with solid conductors and punch down tools, so you’ll need to ensure you can properly terminate stranded wires.

Another thing that might help - a high quality cat5e or 6 will perform as well as a cat6a for short runs (~50-100ft maybe) since the spec is designed to account for longer runs. These tend to have smaller dividers or no divider in them at all, which would cut down the diameter. Belden 2413 is 5.3mm.

Hope this gives you some place to start your search!

Answer (score -1):

As you may know, Ethernet only uses two of the four strands in a Cat5 cable. So, depending on your intended use, you might be able to get by with much thinner cables. I have a number of Ethernet patch cables with only two strands. They are very thin — about 1 mm in diameter. Some of them are 15 feet long, and they work fine, and I think I’ve even seen 30 foot ones. However, I bought them in Japan, and I don’t know if similar cables are available in the US. [These](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01B1HTQOQ) are close, but mine are quite a bit thinner.

And I’m assuming that cabling that works in patch cables would also work in your walls. That might not be true — beyond my expertise.

Comment: 100Mb ethernet uses 2 pairs, Gb ethernet uses 4 pairs.

Comment: Higher speeds require all four pairs in a high quality cable.   Installing cables that can be used only in limited ways and only when very short is not good advice for permanent in wall wiring.